# How do I stop my navbar from splitting buttons in mobile?

Tags: html, css

I'm a newbie and I'm making my portfolio for practice, and decided I want to make it fully reponsive and use flexbox as much as possible. 
I'm using a "mobile-first" approach, so I can fix any ugliness for desktop later. 
My top navigation bar splits my buttons on mobile view. For example, the "About Me" button is in two lines, and the "me" part overlaps with the "about". I want them all to fit in one line, or two split over two lines, but neatly and without overlapping or cutting off text.

Here's my code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {

}
.nav-container {
  display: flex;

}

nav {
  display: flex;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: fixed;

}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul li {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.header-container {

}

header {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
position: relative;
top: 100px;
}

.headings {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
}

.cv-container {
  display: flex;
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.cv-container a,
.nav-container a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px;
}

.cv-container a:hover,
.nav-container a:hover {
  background-color: #f442aa;
}

strong {
  font-style: bold;
}

header h1 {
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  padding: 15px;
}

header h2 {
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  padding: 15px;
}

header a {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <meta name='viewport'
      content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0' />
  <title>My Name - Web Designer &amp; Developer</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,400i,700|Playfair+Display:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="nav-container">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>


    <header>
      <div class="headings">
      <p><h1>Virginia Balseiro</h1></p>
      <p><h2>Web Designer &amp; Developer</h2></p>
    </div>
      <div class="cv-container">
        <a href="#"><strong>DOWNLOAD CV</strong></a>
      </div>
      <div class="social-container">
        <a></a>
        <a></a>
        <a></a>
      </div>
    </header>
```

I found some "hacks" online, but I really want to do it the proper way and understand what I'm doing. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am suggesting you to use `flex-wrap: wrap`, on your "ul" tag.

Flex wrap allows wrapping items into multiple lines.